# How to use Annotation initialize any class in Spring4?

Tags: java, spring

This is old way i was using

```xml
<bean id="mybean" class="commodel.MyBean" init-method="init">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userModule"></property>
    <property name="myEmailid" value="${bean.email}"></property>         
</bean>
```

and in Java class i am using

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) SpringContextManager.getInstance().fetchBean("mybean");
```

But i am using latest Spring version how can use annotation to initialize the bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component("myBean")
public class MyBean {

  @Autowired 
  private UserDao userDao;

  @Value("${bean.email}")
  private String myEmailid;
}
```

You can remove the bean declaration in context.xml and add the following to enable auto-detect

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                                 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="commodel" /> 

</beans>
```

If you access MyBean from another bean, you can simply inject it using @Autowired.

If you access MyBean from POJO, you can get the instance through ApplicationContext.

Comment: In this no need to define bean in XML file?

Comment: Yes, it is not required to declare the bean in XML.

Comment: You added <context:component-scan base-package="commodel" />  it mean MyBean class should be inside this package? and every class which should be inside this package automatically intialize when application-context will read?

Comment: Yes. You can add multiple package names separated by comma or you can add multiple <context:component-scan> element.

Comment: Will test and accept your answer ASAP otherwise if any doubt will ask you

Comment: In your answer you did not tell how to create Object of MyBean in other classes it will simply like MyBean bean = new MyBean();

Comment: You want to access MyBean from another spring bean or POJO?

Comment: If you can answer for both that will be great if possible please update answer

Comment: If accessing from another spring bean, you can simply inject it using @Autowired. If accessing from POJO, it is same as how you did before.

Comment: Even if we call it from a JSF managed it will be simpley creating object or something like this  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{MyBean}")
  private Mybean myBean;

Comment: Whether you use XML configuration or annotation to define a bean, generally you shouldn't create a bean instance/object manually. In your JSF, it would be same as how you did before; it wouldn't make a difference. You can either use '@ManagedProperty' or even '@Autowired' (try).